# How to union all common columns from every table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, concatenation, union, group-concat

For tables
t1:

```
C1 C2 C3
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

table t2:

```
C1 C2 C4
33 44 55
```

What query should be written to do a union of all common columns so that the result will be this:

```
C1  C2
1   2
4   5
33  44
```

Important to note that I'm not looking for a solution for only two tables but for a solution that does this for every table in the database. DB is SQLite

Comment: For this you would use dynamic sql which is not supported by SQLite.

Comment: @forpas oh I see... but hypothetically what would be the correct dynamic sql query for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not support dynamic sql, so the most that you can do by using its own capabilities is construct a SQL statement that would do what you want and you can execute it by using a programming language like Java or Python.

This query:

```
WITH tables AS (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table') 
SELECT pti.name col
FROM tables t CROSS JOIN pragma_table_info(t.name) pti
GROUP BY col
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tables);
```

returns all the columns that are common in all tables of the databse.

By using `GROUP_CONCAT()` you can get all these columns as a comma separated list which you can use in a `SELECT` statement:

```
WITH tables AS (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table') 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col) columns
FROM (
  SELECT pti.name col
  FROM tables t CROSS JOIN pragma_table_info(t.name) pti
  GROUP BY col
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tables)
);
```

Finally, concatenate the keywords `'SELECT'` and `'FROM'` and each table's name and with `GROUP_CONCAT()` once more and `'UNION ALL'` (or `'UNION'`) as separator construct the sql statement:

```
WITH tables AS (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table') 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sql, ' UNION ALL ') sql
FROM ( 
  SELECT 'SELECT ' || 
    (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col) columns
      FROM (
        SELECT pti.name col
        FROM tables t CROSS JOIN pragma_table_info(t.name) pti
        GROUP BY col
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tables)
      )
    ) || ' FROM ' || name AS sql
  FROM tables
);
```

This will return a string like:

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2 FROM table2 UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2 FROM table3
```

which you can execute.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0dc8f518135945fe22739a867822254f).

Comment: this is brilliant and of tremendous help! thanks a lot!